# DocumentListener not working properly

Tags: java, swing, jpanel, jtextfield, documentlistener

im trying to code a DocumentListener in order to catch the change into a textField.

I have a panel which include another panel in which i put a textField, i have tried a lot of formulas but it didnt work

This is the panel

```
public JPanelTASAS() {
    initComponents();
    txtTASA.getDocument().addDocumentListener(new BecomingYellowDocumentListener(txtTASA));
}

private static class BecomingYellowDocumentListener implements DocumentListener {

    private utilesGUIx.JTextFieldCZ textField;

    public BecomingYellowDocumentListener(utilesGUIx.JTextFieldCZ textField) {
        this.textField = textField;
    }

    @Override
    public void insertUpdate(DocumentEvent e) {
        textField.setBackground(Color.yellow);
        System.out.println("Prueba");
    }

    @Override
    public void removeUpdate(DocumentEvent e) {
        textField.setBackground(Color.yellow);
        System.out.println("Prueba");
    }

    @Override
    public void changedUpdate(DocumentEvent e) {
        textField.setBackground(Color.yellow);
        System.out.println("Prueba");
    }
}
```

The next one is the principal Panel where the other panel is included

```
public JPanelTRANSMISIONES() {
    initComponents();
    anadirPaneles();
}
```

With this code inside initComponents

```
jPanelTASAS1 = new gestionTrafico.forms.JPanelTASAS();
```

And for the record the code of utilesGUIx.JTextFieldCZ

```
public JTextFieldCZ() {
    super();
    enableEvents(AWTEvent.FOCUS_EVENT_MASK);
    enableEvents(AWTEvent.KEY_EVENT_MASK);
    setDocument(createDefaultModel());
}

public void setDocument(Document doc) {
    if (doc != null) {
        doc.putProperty("filterNewlines", Boolean.TRUE);
    }
    super.setDocument(doc);
    }
```

Just to be clear, if if apply this listener to a JTextField of the Principal Panel it works, I think that the problem is adding a document listener to a panel inside another panel. Is it possible ?

Thank you very much in advance for your help

EDIT: I realice that if i change the value of the textfield hardcoding, the documentlistener works. But if i change the value of the textfield in the panel it doesnt.

Comment: For better help sooner, post a [MCVE] or [Short, Self Contained, Correct Example](http://www.sscce.org/).

Comment: I think this example is pretty clear, how can i improve it ?

Comment: For starters, you can read both documents carefully, and ask about anything you do not understand.

Comment: adding a document listener to a panel?

Comment: Adding a document listener to a textField of a Panel

Answer (score 1):

*Guessing*: your problem is simply that just changing the background doesn't automatically trigger a **repaint** of the affected UI element.

In other words: you will probably see those messages on stdout; but in order for your UI to change, you should call `repaint()` on your frame or panel.

See [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/painting/problems.html) for some common solutions to common painting problems.

But given your latest comment, you are not even there yet. I guess you have to look into the details of using a DocumentListener more carefully, for example by studying this [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/documentlistener.html).

Comment: Maybe this is the Color problem but i cant see the System.out.println in my output, its like DocumentListener doesnt works

Comment: Too bad. Then we really have a problem; as your input code somehow looks correct; but on the other hand is really confusing; in that sense: we really need a **true** [mcve] from you - something that **we** can immediately compile and run ourselves.

Comment: Just to be clear, if if apply this listener to a JTextField of the Principal Panel it works, I think that the problem is adding a document listener to a panel inside another panel. Is it possible ? I appreciate your help @GhostCat

Comment: It has been some time since I worked with a DocumentListener. In that sense you probably want to step back and A) really understand that whole concept (I put another link into my answer) B) decide if you really need a DocumentListener here. You see, that listener only makes "real" sense when you gain something from using it; for example when working with your own document model.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is definitively possible to add a document listener to a document of a **text field** located on a panel inside a second panel.

You are probably adding the listener to the wrong document and/or text field; but hard to say without seeing how you are doing it, could be something related to how the panels are constructed/added...

Example (SSCC), quick&dirty just to show that it is possible:

```
package test;

import java.awt.Color;

import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JTextField;
import javax.swing.border.TitledBorder;
import javax.swing.event.DocumentEvent;
import javax.swing.event.DocumentListener;

public class Panels {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Panels();
    }

    private JFrame frame;
    private JPanel firstPanel;
    private JPanel secondPanel;

    private Panels() {
        initGUI();

        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    private void initGUI() {
        JTextField secondField = new JTextField(20);
        secondField.getDocument().addDocumentListener(new ColoringListener(secondField));

        secondPanel = new JPanel();
        secondPanel.setBorder(new TitledBorder("Second"));
        secondPanel.add(secondField);

        JTextField firstField = new JTextField(20);
        firstField.getDocument().addDocumentListener(new ColoringListener(firstField));

        firstPanel = new JPanel();
        firstPanel.setBorder(new TitledBorder("First"));
        firstPanel.add(firstField);
        firstPanel.add(secondPanel);

        frame = new JFrame();
        frame.add(firstPanel);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.pack();
        frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    }

    private static class ColoringListener implements DocumentListener {

        private final JTextField field;

        ColoringListener(JTextField field) {
            this.field = field;
        }
        @Override
        public void insertUpdate(DocumentEvent e) {
            field.setBackground(Color.GREEN);
        }
        @Override
        public void removeUpdate(DocumentEvent e) {
            field.setBackground(Color.RED);
        }
        @Override
        public void changedUpdate(DocumentEvent e) {
        }
    }
}
```

*EDIT: I tried to use the same structures as used in the question. I don't like to have to pass the field to the listeners constructor and to add the listener to the field - error prone!*

Comment: I think im getting close to the real problem thanks of your code, i realice that if i change the value of the textfield hardcoding, the documentlistener works. But if i change the value of the textfield in the panel it doesnt.

Answer (score 1):

I got the answer.

The problem is that I am adding DocumentListener in the constructor, I change it and I call getDocument().addDocumentListener when the textField gain the Focus (txtTASAFocusGained).

Now it works properly.